# TableView as subview with navigation controller

Tags: uitableview, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, subview

I would like to have a view (one of five tabbars) with some subviews (labels, images and such) including a table view, so that the table view will only take up half of the screen (similar to this thread [Add tableview as subview to view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575106/add-tableview-as-subview-to-view)). I have set up the views controller as tableview delegate and data source, but how can I use navigation with this table view (uinavigationcontroller)?

Clarification:
I started out with a tab bar based app, and wanted to have one of the tab bar views to have some labels in to top and a table view in the lower half of that view. I solved it myself, see below

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you want to achieve. Do you want to play around with the `UITableView` or the whole `UIViewController` that has the `UITableView` as the sub-view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was of course simpler than I thought it was. I set up a tab bar controller with some tabs (with individual view controllers). I embedded one of the view controllers in a navigation controller (using the menu Editor -- Embed in -- Navigation Controller). Added the labels and a uitableview (through Storyboard) to the view and hooked up outlets for the labels and the table view, as well as setting the view controller as delegate and data source (UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource).